# Very special join on float value

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I got stuck with a tricky query (in MS Access 2013). I'd like to do a fairly simple Thing:

I have got two Tables (see example below): Table "scores" with scores of an exam and table "grading_key".

The scores table has a field named "quotient" which contains a float value representing the percentage of success (1.0 being all questions answered correctly). The grading_key table has quotient limits which separate one grade level from the next. Thus the “grading_key” table can be used to get a grade for any quotient value.

A grade can be found by performing:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Grade FROM grading_key WHERE {ANY_QUOTIENT_VALUE} <= Quotient
```

Sample Tables:

```
|-grade_key-|        |-----scores-----|
Quotient Grade    StudentId     Quotient
0,92    1          123          0,85
0,87    1,5        321          0,8
0,81    2          766          0,91
0,76    2,5        222          0,78
```

My Problem is, I’d like to join scores and grades in a query resulting in associating each quotient in table “scores” with one grade in table “grade_key” (see desired_result below). Unfortunately I can’t simply join, as the quotients in “scores” do not necessarily match the grade limits defined in “grade_key”. 
Currently I used a VBA function (calculateScoreForQuotient()) but I want to remove the VBA dependency as the resulting table should be called from outside MS Access and in this case VBA functions do not work.

```
 |--------Desired_Result-------|
StudentId     Quotient      Grade
  123          0,85          2
  312          0,8           2,5
```

Does anyone know a way to get desired table with plain SQL? I played around  with different combinations of JOINs and and WHEREs for quite a while now but my best result was to associate all available grades with each student (not really meaningful).

Any help would safe my day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a co-related sub-query to return the grade based on the quotient of the student. You could use Max() or TOP 1 with an order by clause, whichever you prefer.

```
select 
    StudentID,
    Quotient,
    (select Max(grade) from Grades where grades.quotient <= student.quotient) as grade
from Student
```